# Calling a FormDialog and starting it right away

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am playing around with the Bot Builder and LUIS from Microsoft and I am having some difficulties for quite basic stuff.

I have simple methods for responding to LUIS intents and in one of them I would like to call a FormDialog (so based on a very simple model I have) and that's it. When the intent is recognized, I correctly enter the right method and I also see that the BuildForm method of my model is called but then the bot does not go through the fields to ask the user for values.

Here is the code of my intent method (the code doesn't do much, it has no real pupose yet):

```cs
[LuisIntent("SendMessage")]
public async Task SendMessage(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    // Check if the user has already configured its message box
    bool isBoxConfigured = false;
    context.UserData.TryGetValue<bool>(Constants.UserData.IsBoxConfigured, out isBoxConfigured);

    if (!isBoxConfigured)
    {
        // Configure box
        context.Call(new FormDialog<MessageBox>(new MessageBox(), this._configureMessageBox, FormOptions.PromptInStart), async (c, r) =>
        {
            await c.PostAsync("Message Box configurée !");
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // Send message
        await context.PostAsync("Votre Message Box est déjà configurée. Le message a été envoyé !");
    }
     context.Wait(MessageReceived);
}
```

Here is the constructor and the `_configureMessageBox` property of my LUIS dialog class:

```cs
public readonly BuildFormDelegate<MessageBox> _configureMessageBox;
public LUISDialog(BuildFormDelegate<MessageBox> configureMessageBox)
{
    _configureMessageBox = configureMessageBox;
}
```

And here is my model (the form):

```cs
[Serializable]
public class MessageBox
{
    [Describe("numéro d'identification")]
    [Prompt("Quel est le {&} de votre Message Box ?")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Describe("surnom")]
    [Prompt("Quel {&} voulez-vous lui donner ?")]
    public string BoxName { get; set; }

    public static IForm<MessageBox> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<MessageBox>()
            .Message("Mmmh... Je ne connais pas votre Message Box. J'ai besoin de quelques informations.")
            .Build();
    }
}
```

When I send the message "envoie un message" to the bot, it recognizes the `SendMessage` intent but immediatly responds with "Message Box configurée !", which is supposed to be sent *after* the user goes through the form.

Does anyone have an idea about how I am supposed to do?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please show your form, Also the context.Wait(MessageReceived) should be inside of the else and inside of "ResumeAfter" method of the form.

Comment: I added my form code to my original post. I also moved the `context.Wait(...)` call as you said and now I get the beginning of my form (the message + the first field prompt) but immediately then I get an error: `Exception: anonymous method closures that capture the environment are not serializable, consider removing environment capture or using a reflection serialization surrogate: BotTest.Dialogs.LUISDialog+<>c__DisplayClass4_0`

Comment: Right, that's because of the async (c, r) =>. Move that to a method and let me know. Once you confirm I can craft an answer.

Comment: Perfect! It works now, thank you! But It seems that callbacks are quite often necessary throughout the dialog class. It doesn't seem very practical. Is that a good practice?

Comment: I just added the formal answer. Please upvote and marked as answered. You can use anonymous methods but you need to make sure they will be serializable otherwise it will fail with the error. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that you will need to change in order to fix this:

1. Move the `context.Wait(MessageReceived)` call inside the else clause and inside the `ResumeAfter<T>` method of the form. This is required because with your current code you are awaiting after calling the form which is wrong. If you call a dialog/form you don't have to wait
2. Having the `ResumeAfter<T>` method as an anonymous function can lead into serialization issues, so I would recommend creating a method instead. Per the [docs](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/technical-faq/#ensure-that-all-dialogs-are-serializable):

   > **Ensure that all dialogs are serializable.**
   >   This can be as simple as using the [Serializable] attribute on your IDialog implementations. **But beware that anonymous method closures are not serializable if they reference their outside environment to capture variables**. We also support a reflection-based serialization surrogate to help serialize types not marked as serializable.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem although when I added the `FormOptions.PromptInStart` to my code the form started immediately. This is my code and form.

Call from LUIS intent:

```
var searchForm = new SearchForm();
var form = new FormDialog<SearchForm>(searchForm, SearchForm.BuildTestForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
context.Call(form, async (dialogContext, awaitable) =>
{
     var r = await awaitable;
     //handle result.
});
```

SearchForm class:

```
public static IForm<SearchForm> BuildTestForm()
{
     return new FormBuilder<SearchForm>()
         .Message("Start of form message.")
         .Field(...)
         ...
         .Build()
}
```

I hope this helps.

PS: My LUIS intent fills in some fields in my class and that's why I create it before I create the form.